# Exclude similar file names from an array using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have array of files , example `file=[a.yml, a.json,b.yml,b.json]`. I'm iterating using `for` loop. I need to exclude the `.json` files from being executed when it has both `.yml`or`.yaml` and `.json` in the array. but if I have only `.json` in the array (example `[a.json,b.json]`, it needs to pass through the loop. Is that possible with shell script ?

Basically i'm trying to compare the strings in an array and exclude the duplicate dynamically.

Is this possible with shell ?

```
filename=$(git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION)
echo "$filename"
mkdir report || echo "dir report exists"
for file in ${filename}; do
    echo ${file}
    ext=${file##*.}
    if [ $ext == "yaml" ] || [ $ext == "yml" ] || [ $ext == "json" ]; then
        if [ ${file} != "buildspec.yml" ] && [ ${file} != "stackupdatebuildspec.yml" ] && [ ${file} != "specs.json" ]; then
            stack=$(echo ${file} | cut -d "." -f 1)
            stackName="${stack//[\/]/-}"
            echo ${stackName}
            howmany() { echo $#; }
            numOfFilesValidated=$(howmany $listOfFilesToScan)
            echo "=========================================== Syntax validation started =============================================================="
            cfSyntaxLogFile="cf-syntax-validation-output"
            numOfFailures=0
            numOfValidatedFiles=0
            for file_to_scan in $listOfFilesToScan; do
                if [[ $(cfn-lint -t "$file_to_scan" --parameter-values-path "${stack}.json" --append-rules ./append_rules --override-spec ./over_ride_spec/spec.json |& tee -a $cfSyntaxLogFile) == "" ]]; then
                    echo "INFO: Syntax validation of template $file: SUCCESS"
                    ((numOfValidatedFiles++))
                else
                    echo "ERROR: Syntax validation of template $file: FAILURE"
                    ((numOfFailures++))
                fi
            done'''
```

Comment: 1. quote your variables.  curly-braces are not a substitute for quoting, they serve a different purpose (disambiguating variable names from adjacent text).   2. you say "array of files", but you are not using an array. You are using, at best, a single newline-delimited string. Use an array.   3. i don't even know where to begin with the rest of your script.

Comment: @cas Thanks for your inputs. Im a newbie to bash and will make the code looks understandable .

Comment: @cas Thanks for your inputs. Im a newbie to bash and will make the code looks understandable .

The variable file name will be assigned with the list of files that was changed as part of a commit.
So, the values for the filename is dynamic. My concern is, if i commit file1.yml and file2.json the loop will be iterated for 2 times and which does the same operation twice. So is there any way that we can compare and exclude .json if .yml for the same filename is present. TIA

Comment: Please show us (in your question, and formatted as code) the output from the first `echo` command

Comment: You mention only `yml` suffix files in your question text but your code also considers the `yaml` suffix. If this is required please say so in your text.

Comment: You know this code will break horribly if any of your file names contains a space...?

Comment: @roaima. The output of the first echo statement is (whatever files are changed as part of the commit it will be displayed and a assigned to filename variable)


`testinfra.json
testinfra.yml`

Comment: @roaima, the filenames will not have any whitespaces to it.

Comment: So the first `echo` statement is literally a list of space separated filenames? No extra punctuation?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

You can see if you have the other value before moving on: [Check if a bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value).

You could also keep just the `.json` files in the array and check later in the loop for the existence of the `.yml` file.

`bash` has a nice parameter substitution for that:

> ```
> ${parameter%word}
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern.
> ```

In your case, it would be something like this (stripping the `.json` and adding the `.yml`:

```
if [ ! -f "${filename%.json}.yml" ]
then
    # process
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```bsh
declare -A fhash

# Load $files array with 'git show -z' - NUL-separated filenames in case
# of spaces, newlines, etc.
mapfile -d '' -t files < <(git show -z --pretty="format:" --name-only "$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION")

# build an associative array (hash) from the files array, so we can easily
# check if a matching .yml filename exists for .json and .yaml files.
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  fhash["$f"]=1
done

# now process each of the filenames in the $files array.
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  # ignore these filenames
  [[ $f =~ ^(buildspec.yml|stackupdatebuildspec.yml|specs.json)$ ]] && continue

  base=${f%.*}       # get base filename
  ext=".${f##*.}"    # get file's "extension"

  # ignore '.json' and .'yaml' files if there is a matching .yml filename.
  # also ignore .json files if there is a matching .yaml filename
  [[ $ext =~ \.(json|yaml)$ ]] && [ "${fhash[$base.yml]}"  -eq 1 ] && continue
  [[ $ext =~ \.json$        ]] && [ "${fhash[$base.yaml]}" -eq 1 ] && continue

  # The code so far has skipped/ignored all of the files we don't want to
  # process, so you can do whatever you need with "$f".

  # ... your code here ...
done
```

Comment: but when i tried the above snippet, it still  iterates through the .json file even if the .yml | .yaml extension is present in the array.

Comment: try it now.  the `ext=${f##*.}` was stripping the `.` before the extension, but my test was expecting it.  fixed now.

Comment: Great Thanks @cas it works!!.  i'm using aws cli for creating/updating stack. can i use ```${filename}.(yml|yaml)$```  so it maps filename.yml or filename.yaml and picks the file from a directory. is above syntax valid one ?

Comment: I don't know what your question means.   There's nothing invalid about that as a regex but: a) as I've already mentioned, curly braces are not a substitute for quoting; b) where and how do you want to use that?  You can use it for a regex match (i.e. on the RHS of `=~` inside a `[[ ... ]]` test) but not, e.g., as an index for an associative array (that requires a fixed string, not a regex)....or anywhere else in bash (`=~` only works inside `[[` ... `]]`).  You can also use it with an external program that understands extended regexps, e.g. awk or `sed -E` or `grep -E`.